# Passing selected value of dropdownlist as property of Model asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to get the selected value of three properties of my model, using dropdownlist that populate the next dropdownlist using a script.

So my problem is that I replace the EF code by this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("AssetID", ViewBag.AssetID as SelectList, "Select a Asset Class", new { id="AssetID" })<br />
            <select id="Segment" name="segment"></select><br />
            <select id="subAsset" name="SubAsset"></select><br />
```

Instead of that code that EF gives:

```
  @Html.DropDownList("AssetID", String.Empty)
  @Html.DropDownList("SegmentID", String.Empty)
  @Html.DropDownList("SubAssetID", String.Empty)
```

That are three properties (foreign key) of my Model Restriction. 
My problem is that now the modelState is not valid and thus the reference of Restriction is not added to the database, maybe I have to  DropDownlistFor to bind the selected value to the property bu I don't know how. Also, I can post the script if needed.

My Model Restriction:

```
    public string portefeuille
    public int AssetID
    public int SegmentID
    public int SubAssetID
    public int Min
    public int Max
```

My Script for populating dropdown based on previous selected item:

```
  $(function () {
$('#AssetID').change(function () {
    $.getJSON('/Restriction/SegmentList/' + $('#AssetID').val(), function (data) {
        var items = '<option>Select a Segment</option>';
        $.each(data, function (i, segment) {
            items += "<option value='" + segment.Value + "'>" + segment.Text + "</option>";
        });
        $('#Segment').html(items);
    });
});

$('#Segment').change(function () {
    $.getJSON('/Restriction/SubAssetList/' + $('#Segment').val(), function (data) {
        var items = '<option>Select a SubAsset</option>';
        $.each(data, function (i, subAsset) {
            items += "<option value='" + subAsset.Value + "'>" + subAsset.Text + "</option>";
        });
        $('#subAsset').html(items);
    });
});
```

});

Here is my RestrictionController:

```
  public class RestrictionController : Controller
{
    private RestrictionContext db = new RestrictionContext();

    //
    // GET: /Restriction/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var restrictions = db.Restrictions.Include(r => r.Asset).Include(r => r.Segment).Include(r => r.SubAsset);
        return View(restrictions.ToList());
    }

    //
    // GET: /Restriction/Details/5

    public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
    {
        Restriction restriction = db.Restrictions.Find(id);
        if (restriction == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(restriction);
    }

    //
    // GET: /Restriction/Create

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.AssetID = new SelectList(db.Assets, "AssetID", "Asset_Name");
        /*
        ViewBag.SegmentID = new SelectList(db.Segments, "SegmentID", "Segment_Name");
        ViewBag.SubAssetID = new SelectList(db.SubAssets, "SubAssetID", "SubAsset_Name");
         * */
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Restriction/Create

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Restriction restriction)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Restrictions.Add(restriction);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.AssetID = new SelectList(db.Assets, "AssetID", "Asset_Name", restriction.AssetID);
        /*
        ViewBag.SegmentID = new SelectList(db.Segments, "SegmentID", "Segment_Name", restriction.SegmentID);
        ViewBag.SubAssetID = new SelectList(db.SubAssets, "SubAssetID", "SubAsset_Name", restriction.SubAssetID);
         */
        return View(restriction);
    }

    //
    // GET: /Restriction/Edit/5

    public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
    {
        Restriction restriction = db.Restrictions.Find(id);
        if (restriction == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        ViewBag.AssetID = new SelectList(db.Assets, "AssetID", "Asset_Name", restriction.AssetID);
        ViewBag.SegmentID = new SelectList(db.Segments, "SegmentID", "Segment_Name", restriction.SegmentID);
        ViewBag.SubAssetID = new SelectList(db.SubAssets, "SubAssetID", "SubAsset_Name", restriction.SubAssetID);
        return View(restriction);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Restriction/Edit/5

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Restriction restriction)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(restriction).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewBag.AssetID = new SelectList(db.Assets, "AssetID", "Asset_Name", restriction.AssetID);
        ViewBag.SegmentID = new SelectList(db.Segments, "SegmentID", "Segment_Name", restriction.SegmentID);
        ViewBag.SubAssetID = new SelectList(db.SubAssets, "SubAssetID", "SubAsset_Name", restriction.SubAssetID);
        return View(restriction);
    }

    //
    // GET: /Restriction/Delete/5

    public ActionResult Delete(int id = 0)
    {
        Restriction restriction = db.Restrictions.Find(id);
        if (restriction == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(restriction);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Restriction/Delete/5

    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        Restriction restriction = db.Restrictions.Find(id);
        db.Restrictions.Remove(restriction);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        db.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    public JsonResult SegmentList(int Id)
    {
        var segment = from s in db.Segments
                      where s.AssetID == Id
                      select s;
        return Json(new SelectList(segment.ToArray(), "SegmentID", "Segment_Name"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    public JsonResult SubAssetList(int id)
    {
        var subAsset = from c in db.SubAssets
                       where c.SegmentID == id
                       select c;
        return Json(new SelectList(subAsset.ToArray(), "SubAssetID", "SubAsset_Name"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    public IList<Segment> Getsegment(int AssetID)
    {
        return db.Segments.Where(m => m.AssetID == AssetID).ToList();
    }

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public JsonResult LoadClassesByAssetId(string Asset_Name)
    {
        var segmentList = this.Getsegment(Convert.ToInt32(Asset_Name));
        var segmentData = segmentList.Select(m => new SelectListItem()
        {
            Text = m.Segment_Name,
            Value = m.AssetID.ToString(),
        });
        return Json(segmentData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I would definitely use client side JavaScript for this, server side code is for server side, not for complex client side functions, check out [knockout](http://www.knockoutjs.com)

Comment: Yes I am using client side script but it is not my problem. My problem is when submitting the all the form with selected value etc.. nothing happen because the ModelState is not valid

Comment: In the first block of code the names are `segment` and `SubAsset`, but in the second they are `SegmentID` and `SubAssetID`! What are the properties of your model?

Comment: I have edited my question with my model Restriction

Comment: Yes there are Dropdownlist for segment subAsset and also Asset, I post also my script it is better to understand

Comment: Do you want cascaded drop down? ...

Comment: No it is ok all the cascading. What is not going well is to mapp this to properties of my model that is when the user fill the form and select value from that dropdown and then submit, the reference is not created because the modelState is not valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you don't have getters and setter on your model properties.

Secondly, your model has properties `SegmentID` and `subAssetID` but you have named the controls `Segment` and `subAsset` so they dont match your property names. You need to name them `SegmentID` and `SubAssetID`. I strongly recommend use use the strongly typed html helper methods to prevent this, for example `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.AssetID, ViewBag.AssetID as SelectList, ""Select a Asset Class", null)`

Comment: Thank I will try this, but yes there is getter and setter in my model but I just no put them here.

Comment: It doesn't work, there is no overload method for that with 5 arguments that is the error

Comment: What do you mean _no overload method for that with 5 arguments_? [Refer to the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlistfor(v=vs.118).aspx). Who said anything about 5 arguments?

Comment: I try it just with 2 arguments as you tell me, it compiles without error but still the same when debugging and submitting the form, the modelState is not valid and then the reference is not added in db

Comment: I've updated my answer to create exactly the same as per the first line in your question (not using `..new { id="AssetID" })` is pointless since the `id` will be "AssetID" anyway)

Comment: Yes yes I discard it because first I had just add the m => m.AssetID argument in my previous method. But now I put just 2 arguments the populating of dropdown works well but again the modelState is not valid

Comment: Which properties are invalid? Put a breakpoint in your action method and check the model properties and ModelState. You haven't posted your controller so hard for me to comment.

Comment: Ok I put the controller. I already put a breakpoint in if (ModelState.IsValid) and it does not enter in so the modelSate is not valid

Comment: Yes I know. So in order to check ModelState you have to put the breakpoint before `if(ModelState..`. Just add the first line as `Restriction r = restriction;` and check the value of all the properties of the model

Comment: Ok I try it and what I have is that Asset is null but AssetID is 1022 it seems big anyway. But Segment and SubAsset are null and SegmentID and SubAssetID are 0.

Comment: You don't have a properties named `Asset`, `Segment` and `SubAsset` so how on earth do you have values for them. Did you actually do what I said? You **MUST** name the controls correctly! Look at the view source for the page. you should have `<select name="SegmentID" ..` and `<select name="SubAssetID" ..`. If you have anything with `name="Asset` or `name=Segment` or name=`subAsset` then its wrong!

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I do I have named them SegmentID and SubAssetID. I don't know why also I have this parameters maybe it is because of the virtual properties for each AssetID, SegmentID, SubAssetID  that I have in my Restriction model no ?

Comment: ahhhhhh sorry I have changed the id to SegmentID and SubAssetID not the name is it correct ?? I have to change both ?

Comment: I think it is ok with the id because it the script works well, but with name maybe not can you tell me

Comment: Just use the `@Html.DropDownList()` methods for all 3 controls so you don't have this problem - for the second one it will be `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SegmentID, null)` - using these helpers will ensure your `name` attributes are always correct for postback. Then change the scripts to use `#SegmentID` and `SubAssetID`

Comment: I don't know how to thank youuu! Really thank you for your patience!! It works now perfectly!! thank you again!!

Comment: Can you just tell me. How can I do if I want to have redundant properties that is I want to have again these three properties Asset Segment and SubAsset to be fill another time ?

Comment: Not sure I understand, but you can have additional properties for these or anything else you want. The important thing is that if you have a property named `Asset` and you have a html control to edit the value of `Asset`, then in order for it to bind to your model correctly, the `name` attribute of the control must also be `Asset`. That is why it is best practice to use the `@Html...For()` methods - they ensure the `name` attribute` matches the property name.